# Smallest number of subsets whose squares cover the whole square

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, combinatorial-designs

Let $2 \leq k \leq n$ be integers, let $[n] := \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and for a subset $A \subseteq [n]$ let $A^2 := A \times A$ be the Cartesian product of $A$ with itself and let $|A|$ denote the cardinality of $A$.

**Question:** Let $f(k,n)$ denote the smallest integer $r$ for which there exist subsets $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_r \subseteq [n]$ with the properties that $|A_j| \leq k$ for all $j$ and $\bigcup_{j=1}^r A_j^2 = [n]^2$. What is $f(k,n)$ (e.g., is there an explicit or explicit-ish formula)?

**Examples and notes:**

- If $k \geq n$ then we have $f(k,n) = 1$ trivially, since we can pick $A_1 = [n]$.
- If $k = 2$ then we have $f(2,n) = n(n-1)/2$, since the only way to have $\bigcup_{j=1}^r A_j^2 = [n]^2$ is if $\{A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_r\}$ contains all $n(n-1)/2$ of the $2$-element subsets of $[n]$.
- A counting argument shows that $f(k,n) \geq \frac{n(n-1)}{k(k-1)}$.
- The lower bound from the previous bullet point is not always attained. For example, if $n = 4$ and $k = 3$ then that bound says that $f(3,4) \geq 2$. However, it is not difficult to show that $f(3,4) = 3$ (attained, for example, by the $3$ subsets $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,2,4\}$, $\{2,3,4\}$).
- Similar to the previous bullet, $f(n-1,n) = 3$ for all $n \geq 3$.
- I have searched the OEIS, but have not found anything that I am convinced is this sequence/triangle. Additional numerical results might help in this regard.

Comment: If I understand correctly, we have $f(3,5)=4$ and $f(3,6)\le7$, as witnessed by {123, 145, 245, 345} and {123, 124, 125, 126, 234, 356, 456}. Similarly, $f(4,6)=3$ because of {1234, 1256, 3456}.

Comment: Thank you -- I have removed the extremely erroneous computational results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for $(n,k,2)$-covering designs, and your $f(k,n)$ is denoted $C(n,k,2)$.  See https://www.dmgordon.org/cover/

For example, $f(3,6)=C(6,3,2)=6$:
https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/show_cover.php?v=6&k=3&t=2

Comment: Nice. It appears that values of $C(n,k,2)$ are known for small $k$, see for example the references given at https://mathoverflow.net/a/192065/. In particular, we have $C(n,3,2)=\big\lceil{n\over3}\lfloor{n\over2}\rfloor\big\rceil$ by results of M. K. Fort, Jr. and G. A. Hedlund, [“Minimal Coverings of Pairs by Triples,”](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-8/issue-4/Minimal-coverings-of-pairs-by-triples/pjm/1103039697.full) *Pacific Journal of Mathematics* **8** (1958), 709–719.